# ppp options.tty serial by-id

Tags: pppd

When my machine reboots it's a lottery which USB devices get assigned to which `ttyUSBn`.

Therefore I have to rename `/etc/ppp/options.ttyUSB0` periodically.

I've tried `/etc/ppp/options.usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_00000000-if00-port0` but that doesn't work.

Is there a way of doing it?

All I can think of is a `cron` `@reboot` job for `root`

```
#!/bin/sh
tty=$(ls -l /dev/serial/by-id | grep FTDI | cut -d '/' -f 3)
cp /etc/ppp/options.usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_00000000-if00-port0 "/dev/ppp/options.$(tty)"
```

Comment: (ppp in 2023?)  Anyway... shouldn't udev do this for you?

Comment: It's for my 1993 Mac LCIII.

Comment: USB in a computer made before USB existed?

Comment: I would assume judicious use of some udev rules would work.

Comment: I don't know what udev is so I'll go with the `cron` script; never mind.